# How to zoom crop image in selected area

Tags: swift, crop

I want to crop image from selected area this is the image area i want to crop

[image: crop area]

[image: result crop]

this is the result i try to crop

the image i crop is not like in the crop area.

i use scrollview to zoom and pan the imageView, this is how setup to crop image.
i use this method from this stackoverflow

```
class ALCroppedPhotoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerImage: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var overlayView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var previewImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rectHoleView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    var data: Data?
    var rect: CGRect!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        previewImageView.image = UIImage(data: data ?? Data())
        setupScrollView()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let midX = overlayView.bounds.midX
        let midY = overlayView.bounds.midY
        let center = CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY)
        let size: CGFloat = 312
        
        // Create the initial layer from the view bounds.
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = overlayView.bounds

        // Create the path.
        rect = CGRect(x: center.x - size / 2, y: center.y - size / 2, width: size, height: size)
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: overlayView.bounds)
        
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd

        // Append the overlay image to the path so that it is subtracted.
        path.append(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 20))
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

        // Set the mask of the view.
        overlayView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
    
    private func setupScrollView() {
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func snapshot(in imageView: UIImageView, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        assert(imageView.contentMode == .scaleAspectFit)
        
        let image = imageView.image!
        
        // figure out what the scale is
        
        let imageRatio = imageView.bounds.width / imageView.bounds.height
        let imageViewRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height
        
        let scale: CGFloat
        if imageRatio > imageViewRatio {
            scale = image.size.height / imageView.bounds.height
        } else {
            scale = image.size.width / imageView.bounds.width
        }
        
        // convert the `rect` into coordinates within the image, itself
        
        let size = rect.size * scale
        let origin = CGPoint(x: image.size.width  / 2 - (imageView.bounds.midX - rect.minX) * scale,
                             y: image.size.height / 2 - (imageView.bounds.midY - rect.minY) * scale)
        let scaledRect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
        
        // now render the image and grab the appropriate rectangle within
        // the image’s coordinate system
        
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = image.scale
        format.opaque = false
        
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: scaledRect, format: format).image { _ in
            image.draw(at: .zero)
        }
    }

    extension CGSize {
    static func * (lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: lhs.width * rhs, height: lhs.height * rhs)
    }
}
}
```

The image actually crop successfully, but failed if i try to zoom really closely. How i can crop if try to zoom closely.

This is where the crash start when i try to print

```
scrollView.zoomScale
```

```
extension ALCroppedPhotoViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        print(scrollView.zoomScale)
        return previewImageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView has a property `zoomScale` that tells you how much you are currently zoomed in. You'll need to use that to adjust your `scale` property.

Comment: i already tried it, it crash when i try to print scrollView.zoomScale @DuncanC

Comment: Show your code that’s crashing. If you don’t allow for the zoomScale property you won’t be able to adjust for the zoom the user applied.

Comment: i update the code showing the crash @DuncanC

Comment: You said "This is where the crash start when i try to print

scrollView.zoomScale". You did not show the code that crashes. Show **the line of code** that crashes. Or are you saying that it crashes when you try to print `scrollView.zoomScale` from the debugger? We need to know exactly the steps that you are taking that cause a crash.

Comment: the crash message is like this `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f093f90)`. The situation is when user take a photo from camera, then push to `ALCroppedPhotoViewController` passing the image to zoom. The crash show up in `viewForZooming` @DuncanC